# parabolic subalgebras and Cartan decomposition

Tags: lie-algebras, lie-algebra-cohomology, rt.representation-theory

Let $\mathfrak{g}$ be a complex simple Lie algebra and $\mathfrak{k}$ its complex subalgebra such that  $(\mathfrak{g},\mathfrak{k})$ is a Hermitian symmetric pair; $\mathfrak{g}= \mathfrak{k}\oplus\mathfrak{p}$ is the corresponding Cartan decomposition subject to some Cartan involution $\theta$. Moreover, there is a splitting $\mathfrak{p} = \mathfrak{p}^- \oplus \mathfrak{p}^+$.

*Problem:* Classify all $\theta$-stable parabolic subgroups  $\mathfrak{q}=\mathfrak{l}\oplus\mathfrak{u}$ of $\mathfrak{g}$ such that $\mathfrak{l}\subseteq\mathfrak{k}$ and $\mathfrak{p}^+\subseteq\mathfrak{u}$.

*Motivation:* In the article [Dirac operators and Lie algebra cohomology. Represent. Theory 10 (2006)](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=2240703), the authors prove that in such a case there is a Hodge decomposition for  $\mathfrak{u}$-homology of  a unitarizable $(\mathfrak{g},K)$-module. I am interested for which **real** parabolic subalgebras of some real form of $\mathfrak{g}$ there is a Hodge decomposition.

Comment: Isn't $\mathfrak{k}$ only a real Lie subalgebra, not a complex Lie subalgebra? (It's the Lie algebra of a maximal compact subgroup of the underlying connected adjoint semisimple real Lie group, right?) Maybe I am misunderstanding.

Comment: I've explicitly stated that $\mathfrak{g}$ and $\mathfrak{k}$ are complex algebras. So if $G/K$ is non-compact Hermitian symmetric space, then $\mathfrak{g}$ is the complexification of the Lie algebra of $G$ and similarly for $\mathfrak{k}$. One can realize $G/K$ as a bounded symmetric domain in $\mathfrak{p}^−$ which is diffeomorphic to an open dense subset of $G_\mathbb{C}/P$. I think this is called Harish-Chandra embedding. I hope this clarifies the situation a little bit.

Comment: It would be great to understand those "adapted" parabolics I am asking about in the geometrical context. I.e. is there some geometrical relationship between $G_\mathbb{C}/P$ and the real generalized flag variety $G/Q$ such that the complexification of the Lie algebra of $Q$ satisfies the condition above? 

Comment: Cartan involutions are defined for real groups, not complex ones, so let me reinterpret this. Consider an adjoint ss $\mathbf{R}$-group $G$ and maximal compact subgroup $K \subset G(\mathbf{R})$. The Cartan involution $\theta$ of $G$ has fixed-point locus $K$ inside $G(\mathbf{R})$; $\theta_{\mathbf{C}}$ is an involution of $G_{\mathbf{C}}$ that, with complex conj., defines *another* $\mathbf{R}$-descent $G'$ of $G_{\mathbf{C}}$ (not $G$!). Doesn't $Q$ comes from $G'$, not $G$ ($\mathfrak{q}$ need not be stable under the complex conjugation on $\mathfrak{g}={\rm{Lie}}(G)_{\mathbf{C}}$)?

Comment: There is an abuse of notation. Cartan involution $\theta$ can mean an involution either on a real Lie group or on a real Lie algebra. Moreover you can always complexify the algebra and denote the extended involution by the same letter and still call it Cartan involution. You can extended it to a complex linear involution of the complexification or to a complex antilinear (i.e. $\theta (i X) = -i\theta(X)$) involution of the complexification. I've seen both and the authors still called their extension Cartan involution and denoted it by the same letter. Some authors use $\Theta$ at group level.

Comment: OK, my main confusion is expressed in my final sentence of my previous comment:  using $\theta$ as an anti-linear involution (I think this is your intent) we get an $\mathbf{R}$-descent $G'$ of $G_{\mathbf{C}}$ (a "twist" of $G$, if you will) that is different from $G$ (e.g., $G'(\mathbf{R})$ and $G(\mathbf{R})$ are distinct Lie subgroups of $G(\mathbf{C})$) and it seems that $\mathfrak{q}$ being stable under that involution corresponds to saying it is the Lie algebra of a parabolic subgroup $Q$ of $G'$, not of $G$.  Am I mistaken? Is $\theta$ in your question anti-linear over $\mathbf{C}$?

Comment: No, in my context $\theta$ is linear. The real parabolic subalgebras can come from different real versions of $G$.

Comment: Aren't the parabolic subalgebras $\mathfrak{q}$ satisfying those properties exactly those of the form $\mathfrak{q}=\mathfrak{q}'\oplus\mathfrak{p}^+$ with $\mathfrak{q}'$ parabolic in $\mathfrak{k}$?

Comment: @Andrea Altomani: I don't know. Hence the bounty. :) By the way - how do you show that  such a $\mathfrak{q}$ is a parabolic subalgebra?

Comment: Any $\mathfrak q$ of your form is $\theta$-staple, hence $\mathfrak q= (\mathfrak q\cap\mathfrak k)\oplus (\mathfrak q\cap\mathfrak p)$, moreover $\mathfrak p^+\subseteq\mathfrak u\subseteq q$. If there exists $X\in\mathfrak p^-\cap\mathfrak q$ then there is $Y\in\mathfrak p^+$ such that $X,Y$ are part of a $\mathfrak{sl}_2$ triple, and hence $\mathfrak p^+\not\subset\mathfrak u$. It follows then that $\mathfrak p^+\subseteq\mathfrak q\subseteq\mathfrak k\oplus\mathfrak p^+$.


Comment: On the other hand, a subalgebra $\mathfrak q$ is parabolic iff (with the obvious notation) $G/Q$ is compact. Let $\hat{\mathfrak q}=\mathfrak k\oplus\mathfrak p^+$ and $\mathfrak q=\mathfrak q′⊕\mathfrak p^+$. Then $G/Q$ is a bundle over $G/\hat Q$, which is compact, with fiber $\hat Q/Q=K/Q'$, which is compact too.


Comment: Andrea, would you care to write these comments into an answer so I can award you the bounty?

Answer (score 3):

The question needs to be made a bit precise. To talk of a Cartan decomposition in your sense, what we need to start with is a real Lie subalgebra ${\mathfrak g}_0$ with a "maximal compact sub-algebra" ${\mathfrak k}_0$ (i.e. Lie algebra of a maximal compact subgroup, assuming that the underlying Lie group $G$ is linear) whose complexifications are $\mathfrak g$ and $\mathfrak k$ respectively. Now there is the extension to $\mathfrak g$ of the Cartan involution $\theta $.

Given this, $\theta $ stable parabolic subalgebras $\mathfrak q$ of the complex Lie algebra $\mathfrak g$ whose nilradical $\mathfrak u$ contains ${\mathfrak p}^+$, are not many! These are exactly the ones such that ${\mathfrak q} \supset {\mathfrak p}^+$ and whose Levi $\mathfrak l$ (which is defined over $\mathbb  R$- recall that $G$ is the group of real points of $G({\mathbb C})$) is such that $L\subset K$ (i.e. ${\mathfrak l}\subset {\mathfrak k}$). In terms of the (Vogan-Zuckerman)  cohomological representations $A_{\mathfrak q}(0)$, the representation  $A_{\mathfrak q}(0)$  is the unique  holomorphic discrete series with trivial infinitesimal character.

If you ask that the whole parabolic sub-algebra ${\mathfrak q}$ contains ${\mathfrak p}^+$, this is equivalent to asking that ${\mathfrak u}\cap {\mathfrak p}= {\mathfrak u}\cap {\mathfrak p}^+$, and hence the corresponding $A_{\mathfrak q}(0)$ is a representation of holomorphic type.

I believe this is implicitly contained in a well known paper of Vogan and Zuckerman in Compositio (1984?) on unitary representations with cohomology.

Not too fussed about the "bounty". But this is the "final" answer: every such $q$ is of the form
$$ q=m\oplus {\mathfrak  p}^+$$
where $m$ is  a parabolic  subalgebra of $k$.

Comment: I did not see the additional comments. Andrea has already said that these parabolics are of the form $m\oplus {\mathfrak p}^+$. This happens to be correct. 

Andrea has more or less given a proof as well. this is the proof. We have the decompositions 

$$q=l\olpus u$$ and $u=p^+\oplus (u\cap p^{-})$. Since the killing form on $p^+\times p^{-}$ is a perfect pairing, and is degenerate on $u$ it follows that if $u$ contains $p^+$ then it cannot contain any vector in $p^{-}$. By the OP's assumption, $l\subset k$. 

Now, if $b$ is a Borel subalgebra of $k$, then $b+p^+$ is a Borel subalgebra of g
 

Comment: This implies that if $m$ is a parabolic subalgebra of $k$ then $m\oplus p^+$ is a parabolic subalgebra of $g$. So, these remarks imply that every $\theta $ stable parabolic is of the desired form (I think that Andrea should get the bounty since Andrea  has answered  the question completely. 

Comment: Agreed, but since he did not posted an answer I cannot give him the bounty. And thank you for your remarks. 